# incorrect row format returned by DDL

Tags: amazon-athena

I have csv data formatted differently and this syntax works as expected. But when I use "**Generate create table DDL**" option, it does not return the same parameters for row format.

original and correct row format:

```
ROW FORMAT  SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ',',
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
```

row format generated by SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz syntax:

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"')
```

I will like to know how to get back the exactly same create table statement that I used in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. `SHOW CREATE TABLE …` will at best give you SQL that can actually be used, but many times will give you something that won't even run, let alone create a identical copy of the table.

You should use the Glue API instead. Use `GetTable` to retrieve the table structure, modify what you need (the name, the database, and/or the location, for example), and then use `CreateTable` to create the new table.

What `SHOW CREATE TABLE …` does is that it looks up the table metadata in Glue and then does (a poor) conversion of what it finds into SQL DDL. You will be much better off doing the Glue operations yourself.